# Is having variables for action URLs in a razor views a good practice? Can I put them in the ViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, viewmodel

I'm trying to have cleaner views for readability and the ease of modification.

I usually have for each view a couple of variables that represents the action URLs used in it:

```cs
    @model IndexViewModel
    
    @{
        // controllers
        string newsControllerName = nameof(NewsController).ToName();
    
        // calls to actions
        string removeNewsActionUrl = Url.Action(nameof(NewsController.RemoveNews));
        string getNewsActionUrl = Url.Action(nameof(NewsController.GetNews));
        string indexActionUrl = Url.Action(nameof(NewsController.Index));
    }
```

So I can use them inside the view's data attributes for ajax calls in JavaScript:

```html
    <div id="newsContainer"
         data-remove-url="@removeNewsActionUrl"
         data-view-url="@getNewsActionUrl">
        ...
    </div>
```

Then a friend of mine suggested that I shouldn't declare variables in a view because it's a bad practice and why not declare them in the ViewModel of that view in this case the `IndexViewModel`.

I know that views shouldn't have complex logic and should have the minimum of C# code, but is what I'm  doing a bad practice? If so why? and is there a disadvantage or an advantage to have variables declared in the ViewModel of that view for this purpose?

From [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2#view-responsibilities) views and view model:

> Views are responsible for presenting content through the user interface. They use the Razor view engine to embed .NET code in HTML markup. **There should be minimal logic within views, and any logic in them should relate to presenting content. If you find the need to perform a great deal of logic in view files in order to display data from a complex model, consider using a View Component, ViewModel, or view template to simplify the view**.

I couldn't find anything related to this on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't want this stuff in the view model. It's superfluous there as there is nothing to be communicated between model and controller.

I don't see an issue with this - it's minimal logic and it is purely concerned with the view itself. Putting it anywhere else would be polluting another part of the codebase for no good reason.

That said, I don't really see any good reason for the code block - why not just inline it in the HTML attributes?

Comment: Thanks. I founded it to be more convenience to have all the links on top of a view for editing. Also I see `<div id="newsContainer"  data-remove-url="@removeNewsActionUrl" data-view-url="@getNewsActionUrl">` is much easier to read than `<div id="newsContainer"  data-remove-url="@Url.Action(nameof(NewsController.RemoveNews))"  data-view-url="@Url.Action(nameof(NewsController.GetNews))">`

Comment: Carry on, then - I think your friend is pointing their code smell detector in the wrong direction.